# First error: [UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION] ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn Limit exceeded

Tags: apex, api, soap-api, future

We are currently facing a Salesforce platform error I have never seen before;

> First error: [UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION] ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn Limit exceeded

This happens both when logging into the API and in future jobs - the org has not changed for a long while neither has the data-volume. Googling the error yields no results. Previously we faced problems with long requests (10 concurrent requests lasting > 5s). Have created a case with SF to inquire into any logging they might but am wondering if any of you happen to face the same error starting this morning.

Comment: If you have developer support, open a case with them.

Comment: Good examples [here](https://eltoro.secure.force.com/ArticleViewer?id=a07A000000NPRi8IAH) too.

Comment: I am very familiar with the long running requests itself - but that problem yields a different error - I have never seen this nor am able to find any reference to it - to me it sounds like a lower level DML-transaction-commit type of problem.

Comment: Any idea, why this could occur in test classes? We're hitting same exception in a test class.

Answer (score 8):

I've done some more research to this and created a repository containing code to reproduce:

https://github.com/koenfaro90/SFDC-ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn-Reproduction

It seems that these days the actual start of a HTTP request (ie. the reception of headers by SF) is when a request starts counting against the concurrent request limit - potentially the reception of a body and thus Apex-execution kick-off can be many seconds later. This all causes connectivity to be a factor in the amount of concurrent processes your subscriber org is running.

Answer (score 7):

Well, Salesforce support confirmed

> ...There is no difference between the error message
>   "ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn Limit exceeded" and "REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED:
>   ConcurrentPerOrgApex Limit"..

Guess that closes the case, embarking on a wild goose chase to find the bugger(s).